Why do i get "ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down" when trying to run Milvus
I have very simple code:
from pymilvus import MilvusClient

client = MilvusClient("milvus.db")
print("hello")

which prints out this:
hello
Exception ignored in: <function ServerManager.__del__ at 0x7f1b80758ea0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/milvus_lite/server_manager.py", line 58, in __del__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/milvus_lite/server_manager.py", line 53, in release_all
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/milvus_lite/server.py", line 118, in stop
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/pathlib.py", line 1164, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/pathlib.py", line 358, in __init__
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
Exception ignored in: <function Server.__del__ at 0x7f1b80758cc0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/milvus_lite/server.py", line 122, in __del__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/milvus_lite/server.py", line 118, in stop
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/pathlib.py", line 1164, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/pathlib.py", line 358, in __init__
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

As you can see i get the error for some reason. Why ?

MilvusClient is performing cleanup (via the __del__ method) during the shutdown phase, and it's trying to release resources or stop a background server. That is why it raise error as  python interpreter's shutdown process, not when the MilvusClient is created or used. If you have ever worked with selenium __del__ method during interpreter shutdown , which is also common there . See

I can't reproduce this on my Python 3.12 (pymilvus-2.4.7, milvus_lite-2.4.10). I suspect this won't be an issue in a longer-running process where whatever Milvus is doing isn't racing against Python closing down. See if you can make this shut up by adding a silly, simple time.sleep(2)...

As I previously mentioned in the comment, this error is due to the python interpreter's shutdown process, not when the MilvusClient is created or used.
As MilvusClient itself does not have an __exit__method, which will raise an error when used with a 'with...as' statement , we can create a context manager with the decorator present in
contextlib
from pymilvus import MilvusClient
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def client_manager(db_name):
    client = MilvusClient(db_name)
    try:
        yield client
    finally:
        client.close()  # cleanup method here

with client_manager("milvus.db") as client:
    print("hello")


Thank you for the response but with this code i still get exactly the same error, and i don't understand why... The documentation states that i just need to run MilvusClient("milvus.db") and all will be fine and nothing about anything else...

As I previously stated, 'the error occurs due to the Python interpreter's shutdown process, not when the MilvusClient is created or used'. @akx is correct; using time.sleep() is an effective solution. I verified this by reproducing the example, which worked fine with time.sleep(), just like it did with a context manager . I am unable to understand why the context manager part didn't work on your system.
